# jQuery submit working after second click only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I wrote this code that should submit registration form (PHP) using jQuery and iframe.

**Javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '#reg_form_sub', function(event) {

        var error_message_lgn = $("#reg_frame").contents().text();

        $('#reg_error').text(error_message_lgn);

    });
</script>
```

**HTML**:

```
    <iframe name="reg_frame" id="reg_frame" style="display:none;" src="register.php"></iframe>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p id="reg_error"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="email" name="reg_email" id="reg_form_input" placeholder="Email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="password" name="reg_pass" id="reg_form_input" placeholder="Password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="password" name="reg_pass_confirm" id="reg_form_input" placeholder="Confirm password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="reg_submit" id="reg_form_sub" value="Send me a confirmation email"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

It is kind of working, but when I click the button the first time nothing happens.

When I click the second time I get echo from PHP (script submits the form, it creates the account etc, but I get echo only after clicking for the second time).

Comment: why `style="display:none;"`? Maybe your iframe is not focused on startup so you will have to set the focus into the iframe once the iframe is loaded

Comment: For me given code is working..

Comment: this is fine here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added onload and now its working

```
$(document).on('click', '#reg_form_sub', function(event) {

    $('#reg_frame').on("load", function() {

      var error_message_lgn = $("#reg_frame").contents().text();

      $('#reg_error').text(error_message_lgn);

    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First there is no form Tag. If you planning to save data's use button click function.

```
$("button_id_name").click(function(){});
```

Comment: if you read the code till the end you are gonna see </form>, I just didnt copy/paste it well